# Creating a table with values from a WITH Query

Tags: sql, postgresql

i want to create a table with specific values.

`Something like this`:

```
SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('Data1', 'one'), ('Data2', 'two') ) AS t ("ColumnName1","ColumnName2");
```

But instead of using manual values, i want to use values from a **WITH** QUERY

`Like this`:

```
WITH Test AS 
(
Select table1.id FROM table1
)

SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('Data1', Test.id), ('Data2', Test.id) ) AS t ("ColumnName1","ColumnName2");
```

**How do I access the data from the WITH query?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join lateral to the CTE

> ```
> create table Table1 (
> id varchar(30)
> )
>
> insert into Table1 values ('one'), ('two'), ('three'), ('party')
>
> with CTE_IDLIST AS (
>  select id
>  , row_number() over (order by null) as rn
>  from Table1
> ) 
> select q.*
> from CTE_IDLIST list
> cross join lateral (values ('Data'||list.rn, list.id)) as q("ColumnName1","ColumnName2")
> ```
>
> ```
> ColumnName1 | ColumnName2
> :---------- | :----------
> Data1       | one        
> Data2       | two        
> Data3       | three      
> Data4       | party
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=43be3c6aebc0e1d2d1894b1596c5b52a)*

Answer (score 1):

You use like any other table

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (id varchar(4))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES ('one'),('two')
> ```

> ```
> WITH Test AS 
> (
> Select table1.id FROM table1
> )
> SELECT t1."ColumnName1" ,test.id as "ColumnName2" FROM test CROSS JOIN (SELECT 'Data1' AS "ColumnName1"
> UNION SELECT 'Data2') t1;
> ```

> ```
> ColumnName1 | ColumnName2
> :---------- | :----------
> Data1       | one        
> Data2       | one        
> Data1       | two        
> Data2       | two
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=e3758a4468a7756eb8b0a6eeba08309c)*